# Port forwarding in Ubuntu 20.04 causes pings to fail

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward ssh port to connect my servers together. Something like this:

```
Local Machine === (ssh) ===> Server A === (ssh) ===> Server B
```

My Servers aren't in a same location. They're both VPSs. My Local Machine IP address is dynamic.

I follow these steps:

1. `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
2. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_A`
3. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination SERVER_B`
4. `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

After the 4th step my server seems to not to be able to connect to the internet anymore. For example my `ping google.com` will fails with error.
`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

[image: ping error after step 4]

`ping 8.8.8.8` works fine.

[image: ping 8.8.8.8]

Comment: Try removing step 3. Please edit your question with more details. Which server fails, A or B or both? Are they on the same or different sub-nets? Does "A" to/from "B" involve two different network interface cards on "A". Does ping with DNS lookup work? i.e. `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks @DougSmythies for your answer, I'll edit my question.
I test it without step 3 and it doesn't work. 

Server A fails and after step 4 I can't ping anything. The servers aren't in a same location and aren't on the same sub-nets.

ping 8.8.8.8 works fine.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? *Connecting servers together* is kinda vague.

Comment: Certain websites are blocked here (By the Government) such as YouTube, Coursera and etc. I'm trying to use this as a VPN. I have CISCO on the second server, My problem is about forwarding the traffic from the first one to the other one.

Comment: Set up a tunnel using e.g. ssh, OpenVPN, Wireguard or whatever. Or tell ssh to use A as a jumphost to reach B.https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-using-a-jump-host/ for instance...

Comment: Thanks @vidarlo, I used this commands on my previous VPS provider (For Server A) and it was fine, the problem occurred when I changed my VPS provider.